# Can EasyMock object's field/property be modified by external method?

Tags: unit-testing, easymock

Suppose I mock an object that has field named "name", will I be able to populate "name" field through external **method** and NOT through EasyMock.expect().andReturn(), nor EasyMock.name = "hard-code"? So it looks like following:

```
var easyMock = EasyMock.createNickMock(Object)

ClassUtil.methodOne(condition, easyMock)
```

where methodOne (or the external method) contains the following implementation:

```
methodOne(condition, object) {
    if (condition == true)
       object.name = "something"
    else
       object.name = "nothing"
}
```

The intention is so that I can do something like below:

```
assertEquals(easyMock.name, "something")
```

It seems the value doesn't get retained after coming out of the method. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend exposing fields and mocking at the same time. A value type should not be mocked and everything else should not expose a field.

That said, it should work. Here is a working example:

```
public class ClassWithField {
    public String name;
}

public class ClassWithFieldTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ClassWithField c = niceMock(ClassWithField.class);
        c.name = "test";
        assertEquals("test", c.name);
    }

}
```

Note that you do not even need to `replay(c)` since you are acting on a field.

Comment: Thanks @Henri for your response. Two questions though: 1) when you debug, does it capture the value you set? 2) since the goal is for code coverage, would there be ways to pass object into "methodOne" described above, and let the method populate the value?

Comment: 1) It should. 2) Same thing. Setting the value just works. It doesn't matter where you do it.